# Solving for x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = N to get all the unique combination of x, y, z

Tags: python, algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

The problem is I have to find all the possible combination of integers (x, y, z) that will satisfy the equation x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = N when you are given an integer N. You have to find all the unique tuples (x, y, z). For example, if one of the tuple is (1, 2, 1), then (2, 1, 1) is not unique anymore.

```
def find(n):

    ## max of x can be sqrt of n
    n1 = math.ceil(n ** (1/2))

    lst = []

    for i in range(1, n1):

        if (i ** 2) >= n:
           break

        for j in range(1, (i + 1)):
           if (i ** 2 + j ** 2) >= n:
               break
           if (i ** 2 + i ** 2 + i ** 2) < n:
               break

           for k in range(1, (j + 1)):
              if (i ** 2 + j ** 2 + j ** 2) < n:  
                 break
              if (i ** 2 + j ** 2 + k ** 2) > n:       
                 break
              if i ** 2 + j ** 2 + k ** 2 == n:
                 a = [i, j, k]
                 lst.append(a)
    return lst
```

I tried to make some optimizations. For example, I would stop going through the loop when it is not possible to satisfy the equation anymore. But it's still not optimized. I have a test case with a 8 digit integer, e.g 12345678. My code is taking quite a while to solve 8 digit integer.

Is there any other optimization can be made? 
Thank you!

Comment: i think the k loop is unnecessary. Just check if square root of n -i^2-j^2 is an integer. (care for numerical issues). Also in the j loop you can calculate the bounds for which you break the loop ones and put them into the range of the for loop.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but this is basically a geometric problem. You want to find all grid intersections (from whole numbers) that the 3d sphere with center (0,0,0) and radius sqrt(N) intersects with. If it does not help to solve the problem directly, it might at least help to narrow down the number of possible combinations to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

This is the recent working code which provides unique values and uses a `list`.

```
import math


def find(n):
    # max of x can be sqrt of n
    n1 = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))
    lst = list()
    for i in range(1, n1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n1):

            if i**2 + j**2 >= n:
                break

            tz = int(math.sqrt(n - i**2 - j**2))
            if tz ** 2 == n - i**2 - j**2:

                #This if-block makes the elements in tuple, sorted.
                #so that set can compare two values for equality
                #because (1, 2, 3) != (2, 3, 1)
                if tz < i:
                    i, j, tz = tz, i, j
                elif tz < j:
                    j, tz = tz, j
                lst.append((i, j, tz))
    lst.sort()
    j = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        lst[j] = lst[i]
        if lst[i] != lst[j]:
            i = i + 1
        while i < len(lst) and lst[i] == lst[j]:
            i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

    lst = lst[:j]
    return lst

print find(12345678)
```

---

Your solution can definitely be optimized. The loop in which `k` iterates is not required. You can use simple mathematics to get rid of that third loop.

My `python` skills are a bit rusty but the following code works.

```
import math


def find(n):
    # max of x can be sqrt of n
    n1 = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))
    lst = []

    for i in range(1, n1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n1):

            if i**2 + j**2 >= n:
                break

            tz = int(math.sqrt(n - i**2 - j**2))
            if tz ** 2 == n - i**2 - j**2:
                a = [i, j, tz]
                lst.append(a)
    return lst

print find(12345678)
```

Tested: [here](https://ideone.com/jQaV9C)

For **unique values** you could either use a different data structure like a set which maintains uniques values or put another if-check to see whether or not that there already exists a similar entry.

```
lst = set()

for i in range(1, n1):
    for j in range(i + 1, n1):

        if i**2 + j**2 >= n:
            break

        tz = int(math.sqrt(n - i**2 - j**2))
        if tz ** 2 == n - i**2 - j**2:

            #This if-block makes the elements in tuple, sorted.
            #so that set can compare two values for equality
            #because (1, 2, 3) != (2, 3, 1)
            if tz < i:
                i, j, tz = tz, i, j
            elif tz < j:
                j, tz = tz, j

            a = (i, j, tz)
            lst.add(a)
```

Tested: [here](https://ideone.com/jhLfmP)

#### OR

If you want to continue with the list, you can add another check and append to the list only when current set of values is not in the list.

```
if tz < i:
    i, j, tz = tz, i, j
elif tz < j:
    j, tz = tz, j
a = [i, j, tz]
if not(a in lst):
    lst.append(a)
```

Both come at there costs of increased time complexity. But, IMO using `set` is much suited since it's average case complexity is `O(1)` while for searching an element in `list` for it's existence is `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes, this will work. Only problem is it allows non-unique tuples but that is not a big problem to solve. Thanks!

Comment: I've made an edit to the post. I actually forgot about unique values. :p

Answer (score 3):

Here are some minor optimizations you can do on top of @vishal-wadhwa's.

You can check that any square divided by 8 gives residue 0 or 4 or 1.
Using this you can for example immedately tell that if n divided by 8 has residue 7 there is no solution.

If n is a multiple of 4 there are only even solutions, so you can divide by 4 and solve for that.

Finally, if n divided by four gives residue 1, 2 or 3 there must be 1, 2 or 3 odd numbers in the solution and 2, 1 or 0 even numbers.

The code below uses all this to cut a few corners.

```
import math

def new_find(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [(0, 0, 0)]
    f = 1
    while n % 4 == 0:
        n //= 4
        f *= 2
    if f > 1:
        return [(f*a, f*b, f*c) for (a, b, c) in find(n)]
    if n % 8 == 7:
        return []

    offs = 0 if n % 4 == 1 else 1
    split = 3 if n % 4 == 3 else 2

    sol = []
    for i in range(offs, n, 2):
        if i*i > n // split:
            break
        for j in range(i, n, 2):
            if j*j > (n - i*i) / (split-1):
                break
            rem = n - i*i - j*j
            rs = int(math.sqrt(rem))
            if rem == rs*rs:
                sol.append((i, j, rs))
    return sol

def orig_find(n):
    lst = set()
    n1 = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(0, n1):
        for j in range(i, n1):

            if i**2 + j**2 >= n:
                break

            tz = int(math.sqrt(n - i**2 - j**2))
            if tz ** 2 == n - i**2 - j**2:

                #This if-block makes the elements in tuple, sorted.
                #so that set can compare two values for equality
                #because (1, 2, 3) != (2, 3, 1)
                if tz < i:
                    i, j, tz = tz, i, j
                elif tz < j:
                    j, tz = tz, j

                a = (i, j, tz)
                lst.add(a) 
    return lst

def check_equal(a, b):
    import operator
    return all(map(operator.eq, sorted(map(sorted, a)), sorted(map(sorted, b))))

print(check_equal(new_find(12345678), orig_find(12345678)))

# True
```